# How to access an existing SQLite Database from another project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, project

I have 2 projects in Eclipse.
The first project calls a method from the second project handing it an object the second project shall write into an existing SQLite Database residing in the second project.
However, I get the following error:

```
opening db: 'tomato.db': Zugriff verweigert
```

Zugriff verweigert is German for *access denied*.

How can I allow the db access from the first project to the database file tomato.db residing in the second project?

Answer (score 2):

### ***Solution***

I use sqlite-jdbc from [xerial](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc).
In their tutorial they get the database connection with this line:

```
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:yourdatabasefile.db");
```

However, this doesn't work from another project in Eclipse.
The solution is actually pretty trivial:

```
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\path\\to\\your\\database\\file\\yourdatabasefile.db");
```

Another solution is to use the in-memory sqlite database like this:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
```

Hope this helps.